# How to override an HTML file in a custom module

Tags: magento2

I am developing a custom module for a payment method in magento 2. Currently I am using **cc-form.html** from the vendor directory and the module is working fine. see below path.

> vendor/magento/module-payment/view/frontend/web/template/payment/cc-form.html

Is there any way to override the HTML file?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, there is. You can look in pub static to see how path to static asset constructed.

### How it works

Every asset is accessible from the page by it`enter code here`s "RequireJS ID". It similar to real path, but varied.

For example file `http://magento.vg/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/Magento_Theme/favicon.ico`.

It's real path is `/app/code/Magento/Theme/view/adminhtml/web/favicon.ico`.
It's RequireJS ID is `Magento_Theme/favicon.ico`. This means that file could be accessible via `require("text!Magento_Theme/favicon.ico")` or similar command.

You can find that *RequireJS ID* consist with module name and useful part of path (after folder `web`).

### How can I replace a file

So you have file
`vendor/magento/module-payment/view/frontend/web/template/payment/cc-form.html`

On the page it loaded with src as
`http://magento.vg/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/Magento_Payment/template/payment/cc-form.html`

So its RequireJS ID is
`Magento_Payment/template/payment/cc-form.html`

Side note: Inside UI components stuff it equals to `Magento_Payment/payment/cc-form`. Words "template" and ".html" are added automatically.

And now you can replace this file for application via RequireJS config

```
var config = {
  "map": {
    "*": {
      "Magento_Payment/template/payment/cc-form.html": 
          "<OwnBrand>_<OwnModule>/template/payment/cc-form.html"
    }
  }
};
```

This code snippet you place in `requirejs-config.js` file in your module. That is all.

Comment: An additional note of use: in my case the template was for an **admin UI component**, which had a path map included like so: `'ui/template': 'Magento_Ui/templates'` (see Composer-based file at `vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/requirejs-config.js`). Therefore, in my re-map entry, the target path (left side) had to be changed from `Magento_Ui/template/form/element/media.html` to  `ui/template/form/element/media.html`.